# React Native rerendering only certain components

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, rerender

Let's say I have 10 or more components in my page, now whenever I changed the state using setState, react native re render all of the components (the one that change and all others that doesn't actually need to change).

How do I make react native to only re render some of the components that affected by the state changed ? I read somewhere that you could do it using key props, but have no example on how to.

```
export default class MyApp extends React.Component({

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            result: ''
        }
    }

    LoadChild() {
        // Some functions that load a tabnavigator component
    }

    render() {
        return(
            <View style={{ flex: 1}}>
                <ParentComponent>
                    <Text>
                        //Some Text that need to be updated
                        { this.state.result }
                    </Text>

                    <ChildComponent>
                        { this.LoadChild() }
                    </ChildComponent>
                </ParentComponent>
            </View>
        );
    }
});
```

Whenever I call a function that change the state like setState({ result: 'test' }), I need the text in ParentComponent to re render showing the current state, but this also cause the ChildComponent to re render, causing function LoadChild() to fire again, and so componentDidMount() also fire again. I want the state to only affect the text in ParentComponent whenever state changes.

Answer (score 1):

So I know this answer is late, but I was wondering myself and then I coded something up. Ternary operators are allowed in your return if encapsulated by curly braces. As a result, you can check if values are equal to other values and thus compare state.

Example one using a state value that is a Boolean:

```
<Text>Some Random Text</Text>
{stateVal ? "Thing to Render if true": "Thing to render if false"}
<Text>Other Random Text</Text>
```

Example two comparing a state value:

```
<Text>Some Random Text</Text>
{numericalStateVal === 5 ? "Thing to Render if true": "Thing to render if false"}
<Text>Other Random Text</Text>
```

Example three rendering a component instead of a string:

```
<Text>Some Random Text</Text>
{numericalStateVal === 5 ? <ComponentIfTrue />: <ComponenIfFalse />}
<Text>Other Random Text</Text>
```

Let me know if any of that doesn't make sense. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

What you're looking for is `shouldComponentUpdate`. This is documented [here](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#shouldcomponentupdate). Also check out [optimizing performance docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/optimizing-performance.html#shouldcomponentupdate-in-action).

tldr:

> Currently, if shouldComponentUpdate() returns false, then UNSAFE_componentWillUpdate(), render(), and componentDidUpdate() will not be invoked.

keys serve a slightly different purpose, read [here](https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html#keys)

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer, have looked into it ada tried shouldComponentUpdate, as I understood, it stopped the whole things to re render, where I want to re render but only some component, how do I separate shouldComponentUpdate so that it only re render certain component ? I have updated and added some codes for better understanding.